# Assign random number by group

Tags: random, sas

I am trying to assign a the same random number to each observation within a group. Thus in the dataset below, the value of the variable "random" would be equal for each observation where gp=B, and would take another value for each observation where gp=A, and so on.

```
data test ;
input gp $ a b c ;
datalines;
B 2 2 3
B 2 2 3
A 1 2 3
A 1 2 3
C 3 3 4
C 3 3 4
;
```

Stupidly I tried to create a different seed for each group based upon common unique values to each group:

```
data test2 ;
set test ;

seed = a*b*c ;
random = ranuni(seed) ;

run ;
```

This creates a common starting point per group, but which obviously changes for each observation.

How can I obtain a random number equivalent for each observation in the group? Due to the very large size of the real dataset I would like to avoid any sorting or other time consuming processes.

The required datset would thus look something like:

```
data want ;
input gp $ a b c random ;
datalines;
B 2 2 3 0.123
B 2 2 3 0.123
A 1 2 3 0.456
A 1 2 3 0.456
C 3 3 4 0.789
C 3 3 4 0.789
;
```

Comment: Is the data in any logical order as shown?

Comment: The data is ordered by the ID of each group.

Comment: Changing the seed does _not_ change the random number stream if you're using `ranuni` function.  Only `call ranuni` would allow you to modify the stream mid-data step.  The `seed` call there does absolutely nothing after the first row/iteration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this should do the trick, ask me if you have any questions:

```
proc sort data=test;
by gp;
run;

data test2;
drop seed;
set test;
by gp;
retain random;
if first.gp then do;
  seed = a*b*c ;
  random = ranuni(seed) ;
end;
run;
```

basically, each time you call ranuni you get a new random number, so you only want to call it when the id (gp) changes.

Comment: You should remove the `seed` call (or move it out of the loop), as it's currently not doing anything except the first time.  It should be either just an assignment on its own or (correctly, though I do sometimes skip this for simplicity) in an `if _n_ = 1` block.

Comment: Would using `by gp notsorted` make a difference? I ask in the case that removing the `proc sort`would cut down running time on unsorted datasets.

Comment: that will work.  If you like the answer please check the checkmark!